# Multiple Columns in an “in” statement (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Can you please advise how i can implement this sql query:

```
select * from products where (category, category2, category3) in (2, 138, 136, 125)
```

Error:

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 3 column(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply write all columns in where clause like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
  category IN (2, 138, 136, 125) OR
  category2 IN (2, 138, 136, 125) OR
  category3 IN (2, 138, 136, 125)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from products 
where category in (2, 138, 136, 125)
      OR 
      category2 in (2, 138, 136, 125)
      OR
      category3 in (2, 138, 136, 125)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mmm, is this what you intended to do?

```
select * from products where category in (2, 138, 136, 125)
                         AND category2 in (2, 138, 136, 125)
                         AND category3 in (2, 138, 136, 125)
```

Or with `OR` , depends on the requirement .